# Проблемма с draggable и droppable

Tags: jquery-ui

Есть скрипт:

```
    $("div.event").draggable({
      snap: 'table.calendar td.drop',
      snapMode: 'inner',
      revert: 'invalid',
      cursor: 'move',
      helper: 'clone',
      scroll: false
    });
    $("table.calendar td.drop").droppable({
      accept: "div.event",
      drop: function(event, ui){
                var eventid = ui.draggable.attr("id");
                var date = $(this).attr("id");
                if (confirm("Сохранить?")) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "/ajax/events_ajax.php",
                        data: {action:"plan_event", eventid:eventid, date:date},
                        success: function(resp){
                            if (resp=="success") ui.draggable.addClass("event_set");
                            else alert(resp);
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
    });
```

Есть таблица, с td.drop и есть div.event. Когда перемещаем див в ячейку и сбрасываем туда, этому диву надо присвоить класс **event_set**. Но проблема заключается в том, что новый класс присваивается элементу, который остается неподвижен (т.к. стоит `helper: 'clone'`) - это раз. А второе - при сбрасывании сам перетаскиваемый div из ячейки тоже пропадает. Но confirm и ajax при этом отлично отрабатывают.

Если же убрать **helper: 'clone'**, то все отлично, и класс меняется и div остается в ячейке. Но суть задачи заключается именно в том, что бы клонировать объект.

Если есть какие мысли, подскажите!

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: использовать ui.helper вместо ui.draggable не пробовал?

Comment: Да пробовал, безрезультатно. Да смысл даже не втом, чтобы класс применить к дропнутому объекту. А в том, чтобы после дропа клон объекта остался в ячейке, а не пропал непонятно куда.

Comment: А если самому ручками после дропа объект добавлять в ячейку?

Comment: перед confirm делаю **`var el = ui.droppable;`**, в success `**$(this).append(el);**`. И все равно, после дропа объект в ячейке пропадает.

Comment: Да пришлось так и сделать! Переведите ваш комментарий в ответ, чтоб я принял.

Comment: перебросил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно клонировать ui.draggable, или создать новый элемент с учетом заданного набора параметров и вставить в ячеку. Решение в лоб: el = $(ui.draggable.html())